# How to replace text except when it's between two tags in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace, replace

I have a statement replacement to do in php (using `str_replace` or something else). I have this sentence:

```
the sun is yellow when the <wrong>red sun is not yellow</wrong>
```

I want this:

```
the apple is yellow when the <wrong>red sun is not yellow</wrong>
```

So I need to replace a word, except between two specific tags (`<wrong`and `</wrong>`). How to do that with `str_replace` or using a regex?

Comment: Is there always only one `<wrong>` part?

Answer (score 1):

If the string is small, why not use `explode()` to explode it at the tags,
and replace the strings in required fragments, and then rejoin it ?
Or try DomDocument :

```
<?php

$str = "the sun is yellow when the <wrong> This is also red sun not yellow red sun is not yellow some words </wrong> and here is 
yellow sun outside <wrong> , now yellow sun inside </wrong>";

$origArr = array("sun");
$replaceArr = array("apple");
$str = str_replace($origArr,$replaceArr,$str);

$domElem = new DOMDocument();
$domElem->loadXML("<temp_tag>".$str."</temp_tag>");

$nodes = $domElem->getElementsByTagName('wrong');


$index = 0;
while($nodes->item($index)->nodeValue)
  {
    $nodes->item($index)->nodeValue = str_replace($replaceArr,$origArr,$nodes->item($index)->nodeValue);
    $index++;
  }

echo $domElem->saveHTML();

/* remove the <temp_tags> ....*/

?>
```

See it here:
http://codepad.org/T5o3shB4

Answer (score 0):

the difference is sun -> apple in the second word. for that example str_replace('sun', 'apple', $text, 1) will do just the first one